# knockoutjs - Calculated Attr passing a parameter doesn't work in <IE9

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have an app where I have a template that I'll use for form inputs.

Since there will be multiple versions of the same input/label on the page the input ids can't be hard-coded.

Rather, I've built a function that I'll use to bind the attr ('id' for inputs, 'for' for labels).

This works great in Chrome and IE9, but fails in IE8 & IE7.

I have a label & input:

```
<label data-bind="attr: {for: doId('name_first')}">First Name*</label>
<input type="text" name="name-first" data-bind="value: name_first, attr: {id: doId('name_first')}" />
```

My knockout code:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.person_id = ko.observable('1234');
    self.name_first = ko.observable();

    self.doId = function(seed){
        return seed + "-" + self.person_id();
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/uNCbf/) doesn't seem to work in IE8, so here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/utulan/1/edit).

Anyone experienced this and have a workaround?

Repeating template with input/labels HAS to be a common problem.

-- Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript and can cause issues in IE < 9 when used as a property name.  The solution is to put quotes around `for` like:

```
attr: { 'for': doId('name_first') }
```